# Spring 3 MVC - Map request parameters with prefix to a single bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have the following GET request:

`/api/search?filter.operation=Ping&filter.namespace=`

Please note the parameter names include a prefix (**filter.** operation, **filter.** namespace).

Then, I have the following bean I want to use to receive those parameters:

```
class MessageSearchFilter {
    String operation;
    String namespace;
    ...
}
```

And the handler method has the following signature:

`public @ResponseBody String searchMessages(MessageSearchFilter filter, ...);`

However this doesn't work as Spring MVC expects 'operation' and 'namespace' attributes to named exactly like that. It works if I change my request to use 'operation' and 'namespace' (with no 'filter.' prefix).

Is there any way I can tell Spring to expect parameters to be prefixed with 'filter'?

A side question related to this is, what happens if I have a method signature with several form objects with colliding property names?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to map incoming querystring parameters using `@RequestParam`, and you can fully qualify them:

```
//Your @RequestMapping here...
public @ResponseBody String searchMessages(
  @Requestparam("filter.operation") String filterOperation,
  @RequestParam("filter.namespace") String filterNamespace) {
    MessageSearchFilter messageSearchFilter = new MessageSearchFilter();
    messageSearchFilter.operation = filterOperation;
    messageSearchFilter.namespace = filterNamespace;
    //do your thing here...
}
```

You will also notice that you should be able to now add qualifiers for other objects with property name collisions.

Comment: Thanks, however, I was looking for a way to avoid manually creating and setting bean values myself. I'd expect this to work somehow because Spring does this correctly for nested beans.

Comment: I'm also interested if there is a Spring way to directly inject those properties into the bean?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your controller the method

```
@Override
protected String getFieldBindingPrefix() {
    return "filter.";
}
```

should do the job.

Comment: Can you explain the answer a bit more? I have found nothing about that method on Google. There is neither any "getFieldBindingPrefix()" method to override in my controller class. :-(

Comment: That also doesn't work for "several form objects with colliding property names"